# Match and Merge two columns with data corresponding to third cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

First of all sorry for the title, as it might not be accurate with the problems I am facing, but its related to it. Its quite complicated. 

I have an excel sheet like this

```
Date       | Time   | Table | Bill Number | Unique ID | Status <br>
2019/01/01  0:20:00     A1       0            ABCDEF    Checkin
2019/01/01  0:25:00     A1       112          ABCDEF    First Order
2019/01/01  0:26:00     A1       112          ABCDEF    Default
2019/01/01  0:27:00     A1       112          ABCDEF    Checkout
```

Here I am trying to get the total time duration of `Table` `A1` from `checkin` to `checkout`
`Checkin`time is 0:20:00 and `checkout` time is `0:27:00` meaning 7 minutes. 
But the problem is checkin is doesnt show bill number, bill number only shows when there is `First Order`, `112` is bill number of `A1`. 
What I want is to link `unique ID` with `Table` and merge `Bill Number` so that I can calculate the time duration from `Bill Number`.
Or what may be the best solution to fetch the time duration of `A1` with `112` as Bill number, from checkin to chekout. ?

Since Unique ID is Unique and is linked as soon as customer`checkin` , it is also linked with same customer, same table and same bill number issued after `firstorder`

Comment: With the newest Excel versions you could use `=MAXIFS(B2:B5,E2:E5,"ABCDEF")-MINIFS(B2:B5,E2:E5,"ABCDEF")`. Otherwise create an array function out of `MAX` and `IF`

Comment: This is for the case if it have `ABCDEF` right? But I have a long list of this data, and unique code are different. The Bill number is issued only at chekin, So How Do i merge in case of many Unique ID

Comment: What do you mean, you intend to have a column with times for each row? Just enter the formula in column G, refer to column E for your id and have absolute lookup ranges.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question for learning how to build up your logical solution in Excel.

Create lots of new columns to the right of your data. Don't worry about using too many, just get the logic right. I'm going to assume your data is in columns A-F, and we're working with row 3. As an example.

Column G should be `CheckoutID`:

```
=IF(F3="Checkout", E3, "")
```

If you use something like that you'll isolate in your new column all of the Checkout rows. So you'll have one value there per `UniqueID`.

As far as I can tell, the only piece of information you need which isn't on that row is the checkin time.

So in column H we do the tricky part:

```
=IF(G3="","",MAXIFS(B:B,E:E,G3,F:F,"Checkin"))
```

This says that if we have a value in G3, so this is a Checkout row, then look for the maximum of all checking times (B:B) where our G3 value matches the value in the original Unique ID column (E:E). And then ensure that we're only looking for "Checkin" in the message column (F:F).

It should bring a value back into the result column of the checkin time, but only on the checkout row. It might look like a number, but if you format the column as a time it will look like your Time column. Times are just fractions of a day.

If you then on that row take the difference between this value and column B, you'll have the number of days they were there. You want minutes so multiply by the number of minutes in a day which is 1440.

Column I:

```
=IF(G3="","",(B3-H3) * 60 * 24)
```

Filter out the blank rows and that should do it.

Comment: BTW you could do it all in one column if you want, but this way you get to see the logical steps a little better and then if you want you can condense them. This ended up only being three columns.